# Creating a database with SQLAlchemy once without recreating it every time the program runs

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

My program is built to buy and sell (fake) shares of a stock, then add each transaction to a database. I'm using SQLAlchemy to create the database and tables, and so far it works great. There is one rather large issue though: Since I create the tables within my program (and my program is constantly looping), every time it loops the tables are recreated.

Tables:

```
class Wallet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'wallets'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('wallet_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    balance = Column(Integer())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Wallet(name='%s', balance='%s')>" % (self.name, self.balance)

class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transactions'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('transaction_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    stock = Column(String(50))
    symbol = Column(String(50))
    buy_or_sell = Column(String(50))
    price = Column(Integer())
    ema = Column(Integer())
    shares = Column(Integer())
    time = Column(String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Transaction(stock='%s', symbol='%s', buy_or_sell='%s', price='%s', ema='%s', shares='%s', time='%s')>" % (self.stock, self.symbol, self.buy_or_sell, self.price, self.ema, self.shares, self.time)
```

I tried to relocate the tables to another Python file and import them so I could loop the main program over and over without recreating them.

```
bin/
    main.py
    databases.py
    __init__.py
```

But the issue is persisting. I'm guessing it's because every time classes `Wallet` and `Transaction` are imported it recreates the tables. Or maybe it's just that the database create_all function (`Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`) is still in main.py and runs on every loop.

How do I create the database once and then update its rows/columns every time main.py runs?

Comment: ``create_all`` by itself won’t delete the existing database. The code you are showing should not do what you describe, please show your loop and other relevant sqlalchemy calls.

Comment: Yes my full code is located here https://github.com/Logicmn/PYX/blob/master/PYX.py

Comment: Try using an actual file instead of the sqlite in-memory database. I suspect that for some reason the database gets deleted between the loops.

Comment: Ah yes I had someone else suggest that to me, could you direct me to a tutorial on how to do that? I'm rather new to SQL and SQLAlchemy. I know I'll have to replace `sqlite:///:memory:` in `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)`, but with what?

Comment: For example ``sqlite:////path/to/some/directory/foo.sqlite``.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Jonas for answering my question. By creating the database in temporary memory it was being deleted every loop. The solution is using an actual file instead.